# Factorial function returns 1 when n > 17, for seemingly no reason

Tags: java

I wrote a function in java for factorials so that I could calculate e, but when I input a number greater than 17, I always get out 1.

This is the function:

```
public int fact(int n) {
    for(int i = n-1; i > 1; i--) {
        n *= i;
    }
    if(n <= 0) {
        n = 1;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: Look at the max value of an int in Java.
Factorial of 17 is way more than it, this is why it becomes "negative" and then due to the second if statement goes to 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `int` type has maximum value (2^32 - 1, which is smaller than `fact(13)`). Once you exceed this value, the result of numeric operators overflows, giving incorrect results. You can switch to using `long` instead of `int`, which will allow your code to work for (slightly) higher values of `n`.

Comment: would using `BigInteger` solve the problem for all values of n ?

Comment: @Shashwat `BigInteger` has its own limits, but they are much higher than those of `long`.

Comment: @Eran added the `BigInteger` version of factorial.

Answer (score 5):

It's because `17!` is a very big value to store in the `Integer` datatype and If you try to store it, it will cause an overflow in `Integer` which may cause incorrect result.So if `n` becomes negative then `n` gets reset by `1` and you will return it, So you will get `1` there.

Use `Long` to avoid `Overflow` but it can hold the values upto `2^63-1`. For greater values than it, Use `BigInteger`.

Comment: added the `BigInteger` version of factorial.

Answer (score 1):

BigInteger version of factorial.

```
public static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger n) {
    BigInteger factorial = BigInteger.valueOf(1);

    for (int i = 1; i <= n.intValue(); i++) {
        factorial = factorial.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }

    return factorial;
}
```

Suppose you have a look at this [post](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm) on efficient factorial implementations.

Comment: `return (n <= 0) ? BigInteger.ZERO : IntStream.rangeClosed(2, n).mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf).reduce(BigInteger.ONE, (a, b) -> a.multiply(b));`